# Change Or convert colorspace of PNG from Gray to RGB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file, imagemagick, rmagick

I have been trying to convert colorspace of PNG file from Gray to RGB by using
Rmagick(Imagemagick) in Rails.

But its not working as couldn't change it.

`Magick::Image.read(file_path).first { self.colorspace = RGB}`

Please share your comments if any

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning the colorspace via [Image#colorspace](https://rmagick.github.io/imageattrs.html#colorspace) after reading the image:

img.colorspace = Magick::RGBColorspace